# White space on the bottom of the embeded google maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

I am new to CSS so I have copied this code from somewhere to create a responsive embeded google map but there is white space at the bottom of the page after introducing "max-height" property which was not there before.

```
/* Flexible iFrame (for google maps)*/

.Flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Flexible-container iframe,
.Flexible-container object,
.Flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove padding-bottom: 56.25%; from your css

Comment: Thanks, but it is actually reducing the value because if I remove it completely it shows a very small map.

Comment: give container a width

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this issue adding the following style code directly to the iframe embbed:

```
display: block;
```

I also applied it using a CSS class, filling the screen correctly too. Responsive behavior was ok.

Hope it helps!